# Excel - Make a rule to force a three numbers display, "null" replaced by 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, rules

I want to make a rule into a numeric column in Excel.
I have like 800 cells in that column. Each are numeroted from 1 to 800.

My goal is to have a rule that make this change :

*from --1 / --2  / -12  / 800

to   001 / 002  / 012  / 800*      (and not 0012 or 00800 !)

In other words, force a 3 numbers numerotation with 0 instead of blank.

Please pardon my poor english,

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: hi, good news is this is a simple numbering format. can you copy in some actual examples of what your data looks like and what you want it to look like, its hard to understand at the moment

Comment: Hey, I have edited my post with a link ;)

Comment: that makes sense now, see my answer it should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this (other than use Excel's number format option) is to use the text formula

```
=TEXT(A1,'000')
```

[Microsoft's Help Link for this Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a `custom number format`.

First select the 800 Cells this should apply to.

Right click and select `Format Cells`.

The see image below, select Custom from the left hand side, and type `000` in place of general.

[image]

For more info see: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-and-apply-a-custom-number-format-6c308025-35da-4047-9481-c146a12063df

Comment: Thank you for your time. Is it possible, more than just display the 0 in the cells, to "engrave it" in the formula bar too ?

Comment: @Foaly That would mean it would have to be text and not numbers